# Bootstrap mobile menu on 420px and down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to display the boostrap mobile menu ONLY on widths below 600px? Other than butchering the responsive css file? I am thinking maybe there is an easy override I can add to the mobile section of my custom.css file.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using an @media query in your custom.css? http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: Yes I did, trouble is there are a million classes that should be targeted (some floats are removed from submenu, etc). I am trying to find out exactly what class I need to target in the media query so I can easily disable it for that specific width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can edit the .less files. You can download them at https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/less but you will need to recompile. If you edit variables.less there a variable @navbarCollapseWidth

I haven't tried this though, so can't guarantee it will work